# Get N rows of category A and M-N rows of category B,C,D etc mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a bunch of items with categories like [A,B,C,D...] I am trying to get random records in such a way that I want a total of 10 documents out of which 6 are of category A and 4 are from category A or B or C or D or the rest of the categories. How can I achieve this with the help of aggregation. My current solution would be to fire 2 separate queries, one for category A and one for the rest. Thank you for your suggestions in advance

Schema

```
let ProductSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    brand: String,
    category: String,
    created: Number,
    discount: Number,
    description: String,
    family: [],
    imageUrl: String,
    price: {
        "amount": Number,
        "currency": String
    },
    title: String,
    updated: Number,
    url: String,
});
```

There are 58 categories currently like "mobiles", "laptops", "televisions" etc. If I want 5 mobiles and 5 of the rest, how can I do that in 1 query?

Comment: can you elaborate this, also put schema and what are these categories ??